# Usage of "which" and "what" in affirmative

Tags: relative-pronouns, determiners

> The  medico  went  to  the  nearest  village  and  there  in  the  bazaar  he  found  various  kinds  of meat  and  fish.  He  looked  around  for  some  time  and  found  that  nothing  suited  him.  His  medical knowledge  now  seemed  to  warn  him **which** meat  or  fish  was  indigestible,  **which** not  nutritious, **which** unseasonable,  **which**  would  cause  **what** disease, **which**  would  upset  the  stomach  and  **which** the  bile, till finally he left without buying any meat or fish!

In this paragraph, I wanted to know the usage of "which" and "what".Are they determiner or relative pronouns?

Answer (score 2):

The online dictionaries classify **which** and **what**, in the way they are employed in your examples, written in bold:

> His medical knowledge now seemed to warn him **which** meat or fish was indigestible, **which** not nutritious, **which** unseasonable, which would cause **what** disease,...

as adjectives, but I would say they are [determiners](http://partofspeech.org/determiner-explanation-and-examples/) because:

> determiners cannot be graded unlike adjectives, which can be expressed in different intensities.

For instance, an object may be big, bigger, or biggest. However, it cannot be "which-er" or "which-est", the same as regards "what-er" or "what-est".

However, some of them (which - s), written in bold:

> ... , **which** would cause what disease, **which** would upset the stomach and **which** the bile, till finally he left without buying any meat or fish!

are relative pronouns.

Comment: They definitely aren't adjectives.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the writer varies "which" and "what" to avoid repetition and make the sentence more readable.  He could have written:

> which would cause which disease,

but this is considered poor style.

Otherwise, the sentence is an example of [*parallelism*](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-parallelism.html), in which, when making lists of things, it's good style to use the same structure for each.

> Some days I feel like my brain is "on hold".  I can't even figure out what to wear, what to eat, what to watch on television, or even what to say to other people.

Comment: I also want to know "which" meaning as determiner in these above sentences.

Comment: I suspect they're relative pronouns, although they might have a more specialized term.

Answer (score 0):

They all belong to the category (part of speech) 'determinative' and they are all functioning as 'determiner' or 'fused determiner-head'.

The first "which" is a determiner of "meat or fish". The others are 'fused' determiner heads, meaning that the determiner and head of the noun phrase are combined, or fused, into the single word "which", which we understand to mean "which meat or fish".

"What" is not fused, but a conventional determiner of "disease".

Additionally, in the second and third coordinates, the verb is omitted by a process called 'gapping'. The missing verb is 'understood' as "was".

Answer (score 0):

Relatives pronouns are related to the subject or object with another clause or part of a sentence, It is used for nouns to express function related to who, which, whose etc. In your paragraph you use too much of pronouns and adjectives, let me show you
 **which** would cause what disease, **which** would upset the stomach and **which** the bile, till finally, he left without buying any meat or fish!
here this star marks words are used as a [pronoun](http://www.partsofspeech.net/pronoun/).

Comment: Please note you must disclose your affiliation with any products or websites linked in your answers, if you have any. See [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/359794).

Comment: Also, a note to learners: that site is full of grammatical and spelling errors.